# Evaluating $\int _0 ^\infty \frac{(u^2+1)^{2n-4}}{u^{2n-2} - u^{2n-3} + u^{2n-4} -+ \cdots - u + 1} du$ for $n\geq 2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Interesting (Impossible) Integral

> Compute 
>   $$\int _0 ^\infty \frac{(u^2+1)^{2n-4}}{u^{2n-2}  - u^{2n-3} + u^{2n-4} -+ \cdots - u + 1} du$$
>   for $n \geq 2$.

My initial thought was partial fractions... But it gets so ugly so incredibly fast that I dropped that attempt (even for $n = 3,$ the expression is inoperable). I don't know what clever substitution to use here really, nothing is obvious to me. Could someone provide a hint/solution? Thank you.

Comment: Since the integrand is $O(u^{2n-6})$ for large $u$, the integral diverges for $n \ge 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2} (-1)^ k u^k=\frac{1+u^{2n-1}}{1+u }$$ SO you want to compute
$$I_n=\int_0 ^\infty \frac{ (u+1) \left(u^2+1\right)^{2 n-4}}{u^{2n-1}+1}\,du$$ The degree of numerator is $(4n-7)$ and the degree of denominator is $(2n-1)$ which makes that you have a problem with the upper bound as soon as $n\geq3$. For example, for $n=3$, the expansion of the integrand is
$$\color{red}{1}+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{2}{u^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{u^3}\right)$$